# Booting raw disk VMWare & VirtualBox machine in KVM

Tags: virtualbox, bsod, vmware-player, disk-image, linux-kvm

I have VM used under both VMWare Player and VBox. It's using .vmdk from physical drive and works under both platforms flawlessly. It has installed both guest addons. I tried to boot it in KVM using:

```
qemu-kvm -hda /dev/mapper/loopVM0 -hdb /dev/mapper/loopVM1
```

But it ended up with BSOD. I think it's about UUIDs and stuff. Here's one of .vmdk files:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=b69d7bc3
parentCID=ffffffff
isNativeSnapshot="no"
createType="fullDevice"

# Extent description
RW 83886080 FLAT "/dev/mapper/loopW80" 0

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.adapterType = "ide"
ddb.encoding = "UTF-8"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders = "1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads = "255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors = "63"
ddb.geometry.cylinders = "16383"
ddb.geometry.heads = "16"
ddb.geometry.sectors = "63"
ddb.longContentID = "c29a4f0e8f9d90de0eb62995b69d7bc3"
ddb.toolsInstallType = "1"
ddb.toolsVersion = "10246"
ddb.uuid.image = "7bb915a2-748e-49c6-8d78-b386c4efa9e6"
ddb.uuid.modification = "ccde1888-faed-47e9-abff-711c530aa244"
ddb.uuid.parent = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
```

What is required to be provided in qemu params if I  want those drives to behave the same way as with .vmdk? It's important to note that VBox and VMWare use different VM files, only drives are shared and no BSODs occured during boot on any of those so I'm pretty sure it's about drives config. Especially Windows guests are quite picky about drives they're booted from.